# Upgrade Magento from 2.1 to 2.2.1 with sample data using composer

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, magento2.2, sample-data

What steps do I need to follow to upgrade a demo installation with sample data from Magento 2.1 to the latest 2.2 version?

Instructions that work for Magento Commerce (Enterprise Edition) as well as Open Source (Community Edition) if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Remove Magento 2.1 sample data modules:**

   ```
   bin/magento sampledata:remove
   ```

   *If you recieve an authentication error like this:*

   ```
   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                   

   The 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json' URL required authentication.  
   You must be using the interactive console to authenticate
   ```

   *you have to copy your stored credentials for repo.magento.com to `var/composer_home` because this is the composer home directory for `bin/magento` commands*

   ```
   cp ~/.composer/auth.json var/composer_home/
   ```
2. **Specify new Magento version**

   For Open Source (CE):

   ```
   composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 --no-update
   ```

   For Commerce (EE):

   ```
   composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.1 --no-update
   ```

   (Replace `2.2.1` with the current version if there's a newer one)
3. **Update dev requirement versions**

   This is necessary if you use the testing tools bundled with Magento. The current required versions can be found here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/composer.json#L76-L82

   ```
   composer require --dev --no-update \
       phpunit/phpunit ~6.2.0 \
       squizlabs/php_codesniffer 3.0.1 \
       pdepend/pdepend 2.5.0 \
       friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer ~2.1.1 \
       lusitanian/oauth ~0.8.10 \
       sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.4
   composer remove --dev --no-update \
       fabpot/php-cs-fixer \
       sjparkinson/static-review
   ```
4. **Trigger update**

   ```
   composer update
   ```
5. **Review file permissions**

   You might need to set the correct file permissions again, for example make `bin/magento` executable:

   ```
   chmod +x bin/magento
   ```

   And give appropiate write permissions to the new `generated` directory.

   More info: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/file-sys-perms-over.html
6. **Reinstall sample data**

   ```
   bin/magento sampledata:deploy
   bin/magento sampledata:reset
   ```
7. **Upgrade database**

   ```
   bin/magento setup:upgrade
   ```
8. **Compilations**

   If in production mode, also run the following compilation commands:

   ```
   bin/magento setup:di:compile
   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```