# Package sjparkinson/static-review is abandoned message in Magento 2

Tags: upgrade, composer, magento2.2.2

I am using the command to upgrade 2.2.2 but getting this problem, how can I do,
thank you!please help!

> composer update
>
> Running composer as root/super user is highly discouraged as packages,
>   plugins and scripts cannot always be trusted
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Nothing to install or update
>
> **Package sjparkinson/static-review is abandoned, you should avoid using**
>   **it. Use phpro/grumphp instead.**
>
> Generating autoload files

update

```
composer require sjparkinson/static-review
Running composer as root/super user is highly discouraged as packages, plugins and scripts cannot always be trusted Using version ^5.2 for sjparkinson/static-review ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 requires sjparkinson/static-review ~4.1 -> satisfiable by sjparkinson/static-review[4.1.0, 4.1.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 requires sjparkinson/static-review ~4.1 -> satisfiable by sjparkinson/static-review[4.1.0, 4.1.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 requires sjparkinson/static-review ~4.1 -> satisfiable by sjparkinson/static-review[4.1.0, 4.1.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not an error, only a warning. The abandoned package still exists, it's just recommended to be replaced. Also it is a developer tool, not needed for Magento to operate.

When you ran `composer require sjparkinson/static-review`, composer tried to install the latest version, but Magento requires an older version. Just don't do this, it's not necessary.

Your actual problem is something else: `composer update` alone won't update Magento, because in `composer.json` Magento itself is locked to a specific version. That's why you get the "Nothing to install or update" message. You have to replace the required version of `magento/product-community-edition` in composer.json.

This can also be done on the command line:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update
composer update
```

If you update from Magento 2.1, read more here: [Upgrade Magento from 2.1 to 2.2.1 with sample data using composer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201239/upgrade-magento-from-2-1-to-2-2-1-with-sample-data-using-composer) (leave out the "sampledata" commands if you don't use the sample data)